# Hairpinning on Virgin SuperHub 2

Tags: networking

I recently got the upgraded SuperHub 2 from Virgin and I've not seen a lot of difference performance wise besides the fact that if I try to access a domain that points at my external IP (to a computer on the network), I am no longer able to access via that domain, it just times out.

Looking around on other Stack Exchange sites, someone suggested that it may be an issue with "hairpinning" or "DNAT". I can't seem to find anything related to those two and the SuperHub 2 on Google, nor can I even see any NAT options when I log into the SuperHub 2.

Is it possible to enable either of these services on the SuperHub 2, either via the web interface or Telnet/SSH'ing into it?

Comment: Most home-style routers don't support hairpin routing, and if they do it's usually always on.

Comment: Would I be able to get the same effect if I set up my own DNS server?

Comment: That's what I'd suggest for sure. :)